# Is it possible to give friend request on facebook using SLRequest in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, social-networking

I am using `SLRequest` to get user details and sharing on facebook and twitter. Also i am using Linkedin SDK and Google+ SDK to get user details on respective social networks. My questions are

1. Is it possible to give friend request on facebook using `SLRequest`?
2. Is it possible to follow a person on twitter using `SLRequest`?
3. Is it possible to connect a person on linkedin using SDK?
4. Is it possible to add a person on google+ using SDK?

if possible please give me a way to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, found the solution to my question,

1. For Facebook graph api version 2.0 does not support friend request (Refer:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/friends/v2.0).
2. we can do it with twitter as follows

   ```
   ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

   ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

   [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
   if(granted) {
       // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
       NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

       // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
       // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
       if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
           // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
           ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

           NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
           [tempDict setValue:@"MohammadMasudRa" forKey:@"screen_name"];
           [tempDict setValue:@"true" forKey:@"follow"];
           NSLog(@"*******tempDict %@*******",tempDict);

           //requestForServiceType

           SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/create.json"] parameters:tempDict];
           [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];
           [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
               NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i Error %d", [urlResponse statusCode],error.code];
               NSLog(@"%@error %@", output,error.description);
           }];
       }

   }
   ```

   }];
3. We can do it with Linkedin as follows.

   ```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox"];

   OAMutableURLRequest *request =
   [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                               consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                  token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                               callback:nil
                      signatureProvider:nil];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   NSString *messageToPerson = @"/people/email=test123@test.com";
   NSDictionary *person = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:messageToPerson,@"_path",@"test123",@"first-name",@"test",@"last-name",nil], @"person",nil];
   NSArray *valueArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:person,nil];
   NSDictionary *values = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:valueArray,@"values", nil];
   NSDictionary *ir = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"friend",@"connect-type",nil], @"invitation-request",nil];
   NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:values,@"recipients",@"Invitation",@"subject",@"ConnectWithMe",@"body", ir, @"item-content", nil];
   [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
   [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

   NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];

   [request prepare];

   [request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];

   OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

   [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                    delegate:self
           didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult1:didFinish:)
             didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult1:didFail:) withPrepare:NO];
   ```
4. I unable to get details abt google plus add to circle.